# Preventing a loop within a loop. How to reduce complexity

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, time-complexity, space-complexity

You have 2 arrays.
arrA is empty.
arrB is full of stuff (what it's full of doesnt matter, but assume it's huge).

When a user does a thing, an item is removed from arrB and that item is placed in arrA.

When a user does a different thing, it pulls items from arrA and puts it in arrB.

Is it possible to do this without having a loop within a loop?

Or to put it in computer science terminology:
Is it possible to do this with linear ( ϴ(n) ) time/space complexity?
Right now I have something that is at least ϴ(n*k)

(where n is the length of arrB, and k is the number of items passed to applyItems):

```js
var arrA = [], arrB = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function addToArray(arrayToAddTo, item){
  if(arrayToAddTo.indexOf(item) === -1){
    arrayToAddTo.push(item);
  }
}

function removeFromArray(arrayToRemoveFrom, item){
  var i = arrayToRemoveFrom.length;
  var temp = [];
  while(i--){
    if(arrayToRemoveFrom[i] !== item){
      temp.push(arrayToRemoveFrom[i]);
    }   
  }
  return temp;
}

function applyItems(arrayOfItems){
  var i = arrayOfItems.length;
  while(i--){
    var current = arrayOfItems[i]
    addToArray(arrA, current);
    arrB = removeFromArray(arrB, current);
  }
}

applyItems([0, 5, 3]);
console.log(arrA);
console.log(arrB);
```

applyItems works, but is not efficient.

Is it possible to decrease the time/space complexity here?

Comment: You can use native tools that will be way faster than manually looping. `removeFromArray` can use `indexOf` to get the position of the one to remove and then uses `splice` to remove it. Also you can work with reference instead of recreating the array every time.

Comment: something like this?- [http://jsfiddle.net/p6bnLdoq/](http://jsfiddle.net/p6bnLdoq/), modified the `removeFromArray` method to avoid loop and use splice method

Comment: I don't see how your current approach is `O(n²)`. It's `O(n*k)`, with `n` being the number of items in `arrB` and `k` the ones in `arrayOfItems`. This complexity is totally fine.

Comment: You might want to omit that `indexOf` in `addToArray` though. It seems to be established that no items are in both `arrA` and `arrB` (and your algorithm maintains that invariant), so you will not have to check for duplicates before swapping an item from one to the other

Comment: @Bergi ... Actually... you're right. it is n*k.... but isn't there a way to make it just n? I mean, you're technically starting with 1 finite array. you're not adding new numbers to it or anything... it seems like you should be able to loop through it once. But, like i said, i'm a complexity noob so idk. Was asking if it's possible.

Comment: @AndrewLuhring: Yes, you can make it `O(n+k)` by using an efficient lookup structure for `arrayOfItems` that does not require looping, but allows you to determine in `O(1)` whether an item should be swapped. With that, a single pass over `arrB` is enough. However if the array is finite (and very small), that hardly matters

Comment: @Bergi if you add your comment(s) as a solution, it is the solution to this problem so you'll get a checkmark and solution points.

Comment: @AndrewLuhring: Done - though only that you can mark the question as solved, not because I'd need the 25 points :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment:

> You can use native tools that will be way faster than manually looping. removeFromArray can use indexOf to get the position of the one to remove and then uses splice to remove it. Also you can work with reference instead of recreating the array every time.

with some other optimizations...

```
var arrA = [], arrB = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0];

function addToArray(item){
  if(arrA.indexOf(item) === -1){
    arrA.push(item);
  }
}

function removeFromArray(item){
  var index = arrB.indexOf(item);
  if (index > -1) {
    arrB.splice(index, 1);
  }
}

function applyItems(arrayOfItems){
  arrayOfItems.map(function(item) {
      addToArray(item);
      removeFromArray(item);
  });
}

applyItems([0, 5, 3]);
console.log(arrA);
console.log(arrB);
```

Comment: Why do you think that "native tools" are "way faster than manually looping"? Also they still have the same complexity.

Comment: Same point as @Bergi  -  
doesn't splice work by looping through the items in the array? also, doesn't indexOf also loop through the items in the array? Just because it's a built-in function doesn't mean it's efficient to use it.

Comment: the way i discovered the idea that @Bergi mentioned was because I was translating some code from python this one time. the function used python's "sum" function (which adds up all the values in an array by looping through the array. i think.). To my knowledge there is no equivalent in javascript, but even if there were, using it within a loop would not be efficient, because you're already looping in a loop.

Comment: The fact that javascript is an interpreted language make it by definition slower than compiled language. So **it is always** ***faster*** to use the native javascript functions since **they are** compiled in the engine. But hey, give yourself a go and try to beat it. http://jsperf.com/array-remove-loop-vs-native

Comment: @AndrewLuhring: Even in python, try summing elements manually or using `sum` you will see the difference by a **lot**. It's not a matter of complexity but code execution environment. One is a series of bytecode interpreted by the computer, the other have a layer of interpreters and compiler before being executed.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now I have something that is at least ϴ(n*k)

You can make it `O(n+k)` by using an efficient lookup structure for `arrayOfItems` that does not require looping, but allows you to determine in `O(1)` whether an item should be swapped into the other array. With that, a single pass over `arrB` is enough.
Or if you sort your array and use binary search for the lookup, you will have `O(log k * (n+k))`. However if your array is finite and very small anyway, that hardly matters.

Also you should omit that `indexOf` test in `addToArray`. It seems to be established that no items are in both `arrA` and `arrB` (and your algorithm maintains that invariant), so you will not have to check for duplicates before pushing an item to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Instead of making your own remove function, you can use [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice).

So, instead of `removeFromArray(arrB, current)` you can just do `arrB.splice(i, 1);`. That will remove `1` element from index `i`.

You don't need to loop over every element to check if it matches the one you want - just use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). So you can do something like

```
 var i = arrA.indexOf(item)
```

Comment: doesn't splice work by looping through the items in the array? also, doesn't indexOf also loop through the items in the array?

Comment: Yes, I believe it's O(n) for both. I interpreted your question as how you could do it without you having to loop.

Comment: My bad. Shouldve clarified. This is kind of more of an algorithm question than a JavaScript specific one.